# Firefox couldn't understand bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I am using [Bootstrap CDN](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) for my website. It works fine in Chrome, Opera but Firefox.

Here is some message I got in 
[image]

Is there anyone know how to fix that? Thank you very much!

Comment: Those are warnings, not errors, and mostly due to the fact that firefox does not use `webkit` to render css (used by Chrome and Safari). In Chrome you may when see errors on `moz` vendor names. Does it render properly in Firefox?

Comment: Similarly, the `filter` and `\9` warnings are about Internet Explorer-specific CSS.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's because of my css code. I used only `-webkit-box` to style my site.